# How to stop loop that removing elements from Array List when it’s already empty

Tags: java

I'm working on some game project to school and I need small help.  As you can see from code below, I am trying to make units from one array ,`array1`, to fight units from another array, `array2`. Problem appears when `array1` units kill more than `array2` contains then system crash. 
i.e. 10 units shooting to 5 units. First 5 hit and kill all enemies so what to do to stop the other 5 from shooting and proceed to next step in the game? I tried to do `if (this.game.getUnit().isEmpty()); break;` but didn't work…

```
for (int z=0; z < this.game.getSquadMember().size();z++) {
    switch (target)     
    {
        case 1 :            
        {
            if (toWound() == true)
            {
                 if (roll2 >= 6)                    
                    {
                        System.out.println(roll2+" Armour save unit from any damage");
                    }
                else 
                    {

                        System.out.println(roll2+" target inflicted the wound");
                        deadUnits(); 
                   // if (this.game.getUnit().isEmpty());
                   // breake;
                    }

            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println(" no effect");
            }
            break;
        }
            ....
    }
}

public void deadUnits()

{
    int UnitToRemove =-1;
    for (Units units : this.game.getBoyz())
    {
        UnitToRemove = this.game.getUnit().indexOf(units);
    }
    this.game.getUnit().remove(UnitToRemove);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty, `UnitToRemove` will remain as -1. So, just check for this:

```
if (UnitToRemove != -1) {
  this.game.getUnit().remove(UnitToRemove);
}
```

You can actually just remove the item from the list without doing the separate `indexOf` and `remove`:

```
public void deadUnits() {
  List<Units> boyz = this.game.getBoyz();
  Units lastUnits = boyz.get(boyz.size() - 1);
  this.game.getUnit().remove(lastUnits);
}
```

This is because you only ever try to remove the last item in the `getBoyz()` list; and `remove(Object)` is effectively the same as:

```
int index = list.indexOf(obj);
if (index != -1) {
  list.remove(index);
}
```